# Java Histogram from a .txt file

Tags: java, multithreading, histogram

How do I read strings from a .txt file in Java using Histograms and Threads?

Comment: "It's not printing" - does it run? Do you get an error? Maybe be a bit more specific?

Comment: @AlexK it runs but it only prints the time but not the file.

Comment: @kannah - please don't delete the text of your question, especially after people have answered it.

Answer (score 2):

`extract` is never called in `Histogram` (which should preferrably implement `Runnable`)

```
@Override
public void run() {
    extract();
}
```

Comment: @reimeus where do i put it? at mainDriver or Histogram? What part? Thanks.

Comment: @KannahMillano: don't try to simply make the code work by copying and pasting code that you don't understand. Try to understand why it doesn't. Read the tutorial about threads, since you obviously don't understand how they work. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: @KannahMillano this answer relates specifically to `Histogram`... `MainDriver` doesnt need to be a `Thread`

Comment: @JBNizet lol this is actually my own code. I didn't copied it anywhere. I'm still a student trying to understand JAVA and I just don't understand why it doesn't prints.

Comment: I was not referring to the code you posted. I was referring to the code posted by Reimeus. You asked "where do i put it? at mainDriver or Histogram?". To me, that reads as "I don't understand anything to the code in this answer, but I'm ready to copy and paste it wherever you tell me to do it". If you understood how threads work, you wouldn't have to ask this question.

Comment: @JBNizet i actually pasted in Histogram at first because I know maindriver isn't a thread but it had an error. So, I asked him where. Minutes passed, I found out that I had the file directory wrong because it should actually be "c:\\dragonlancebook\\dragonlancebook1.txt" instead of "c:\\mydragonlancebook1.txt". I do actually understand how threads work because I if don't, I wouldn't have this code right now.